# How to implement <mat-chip-list> with single selection instead of multi selection

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<mat-chip-list multiple="false" aria-label="Fish selection">
    <mat-chip>One fish</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip>Two fish</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip>Primary fish</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip>Accent fish</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

I need to implement <mat-chip-list> like user can only select one value instead of multiple. I tried above code but its not working for me. Please suggest changes.

Comment: The mat-chip-list is designed to handle a list of values and that is how a user would expect it to function. If only a single value can be selected I would suggest using a mat-select or mat-autocomplete

Comment: @Bart thanks for the suggestion. I have that option in my mind if there is no solution but i thought we can check can we achieve that in this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this or just delete `multiple` attribute at all

```
<mat-chip-list [multiple]="false" aria-label="Fish selection">
    <mat-chip>One fish</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip>Two fish</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip>Primary fish</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip>Accent fish</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: I have tried above solution but its not working. Also without multiple its working same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this in the TS file

formControl = new FormControl('one');

changeChip(val: string){
   this.formControl.patchValue(val)
}

<mat-chip-list aria-label="Fish selection" multiple="false" [formControl]="formControl">
   <mat-chip value="one" (click)="changeChip('one')">One fish</mat-chip>
   <mat-chip value="two" (click)="changeChip('two')">Two fish</mat-chip>
   <mat-chip value="three" (click)="changeChip('three')">Primary fish</mat-chip>
   <mat-chip value="four" (click)="changeChip('four')">Boo fish</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```